# Converting date format in apache logs to ISO format In Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-datetime, python-dateutil

I have been trying to convert the date format in apache logs to ISO format in Python 3, but I can't seem to get it to work.

I can get it to work if I only include the days, months, and year but not in combination with hours, minutes, and seconds.

```
Text = "25/Jan/2000:14:00:01"
Date = dateutil.parser.parse(Text)
Date = Date.isoformat()
print(Date)

# I receive the following error messages below

 Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:/Test.py", line 3, in <module>
    Date = dateutil.parser.parse(Text)
  File "Z:\Python\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 1356, in parse
    return DEFAULTPARSER.parse(timestr, **kwargs)
  File "Z:\Python\lib\site-packages\dateutil\parser\_parser.py", line 648, in parse
    raise ValueError("Unknown string format:", timestr)
ValueError: ('Unknown string format:', '25/Jan/2000:14:00:01'
```

I have also tried using datetime module (datetime.datetime.strftime()) but the same problem appears.

Could somebody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

This is because the parse() method expects the string format for the date to be of this form: `25/Jan/2000 14:00:01`. You need to replace the `:` after the year with a space.
Doing something like this would work:

```
Text = "25/Jan/2000:14:00:01"             
Date = parse(Text.replace(":", " ", 1))   
Date = Date.isoformat()                   
print(Date)
```